# preg_replace a string, get piece of string an insert into a function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have not struggled to understand some regex, but i can't get it right. I am developing a system that understand some codes ind a included file. Simple. But i need to get some pieces from the string sometimes and replace the string with a function.

Example:
Here is the "code" from the included file

```
{{quicklink("li", "li")}}
```

and

```
{{showcase_small("classy_box")}}
```

Now i have to get these strings and the information inside ("") så that i can replace the string and insert a function with the information:

```
$showcase->classyBox("${1}")
```

I have tried many times, but i cant get the wanted information.

Cheers,

Comment: i can't seem to understand your problem, can you please rephrase\ elaborate?

Comment: I cant get the right code for preg_replace to return the wanted data out of this string: {{showcase_small("classy_box")}} i want to get classy_box or whatever the text is inside ("") and replace the whole text to a function.

ive tried with this: 

$data = preg_replace("/({{showcase_small)\(\"([A-Za-z0-9_]+)\"\)/(}})/", "$showcase->classyBox("${1}")", $data);

But cant get it to work..

Comment: i see you got an answer by Lindrian. let us know if it doesn't work out for you

Comment: Sadly, i didn't tried his regex in my preg_replace, but returned empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have gathered, this should work: http://regex101.com/r/xI7vW4

Very similar to your own expression, so I don't see why yours did not work.

Comment: Tried with `code`$data = preg_replace('{{showcase_small\("([^"]+)"\)}}', $showcase->classyBox("${1}"), $data);

But it didn't work, it just returned {}

:s?

Comment: Putting / at start and end just make the return total empty.

Comment: Oh, found the error, my code had a decoding error. What a shame. But wow, it worked! thanks!